VBA excel if cell empty delete row above but copy cell from above first
Attached screenshot will explain it better....
I am trying to write macro which will do the following:
When cell A is empty, copy value of cell A from the cell above
and delete that row above that cell which was empty… or
In the table shown delete Row 2 but copy cell A2 into A3 before Row 3 deletion
So far I got this but after that I am confused what to do next...anybody can help?
Sub RowAboveDelete()

 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
 Dim lr As Long
 lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

 Dim i As Long
 For i = lr To 1 Step -1
   If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Then
   ws.Rows(i).Offset(-1).Delete
  
   End If
Next i

End Sub     



Remove Old Data, Keep First Old Column

Main
Sub RemoveOldData()
       
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Remove Old Data"
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const TOP_LEFT_CELL As String = "A2"
    
    ' Reference the objects.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = RefCurrentRegion(ws.Range(TOP_LEFT_CELL))
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(1)
    Dim drg As Range
    With rg
        Set drg = rg.Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1)
    End With
    
    ' Copy the values from the criteria column to an array.
    Dim cData() As Variant: cData = GetRange(crg)
    ' Retrieve the last (range) row index, the first to be processed.
    Dim cRow As Long: cRow = rg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim RowsCount As Long, TotalRowsCount As Long
    Dim IsCellBlank As Boolean, IsBlankCellFound As Boolean
    
    ' Loop from bottom to top.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do While cRow > 0
        IsCellBlank = (Len(CStr(cData(cRow, 1))) = 0)
        If IsBlankCellFound Then
            RowsCount = RowsCount + 1 ' number of rows to delete
            If Not IsCellBlank Then
                ' Delete rows.
                Union(crg.Rows(cRow + 1).Resize(RowsCount), _
                    drg.Rows(cRow).Resize(RowsCount)).Delete xlShiftUp
                ' Count and reset.
                TotalRowsCount = TotalRowsCount + RowsCount
                RowsCount = 0
                IsBlankCellFound = False
            End If
        Else
            ' Flag.
            If IsCellBlank Then IsBlankCellFound = True
        End If
        cRow = cRow - 1
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox TotalRowsCount & " row" & IIf(TotalRowsCount = 1, "", "s") _
        & " of old data removed.", _
        IIf(TotalRowsCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation), PROC_TITLE
    
End Sub

Help
Function RefCurrentRegion(topLeftCell As Range) As Range
    
    If topLeftCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With topLeftCell.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set RefCurrentRegion = topLeftCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
            - topLeftCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - topLeftCell.Column)
    End With

End Function

Function GetRange(ByVal rg As Range) As Variant
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With rg.Areas(1)
        If rg.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
            Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = .Value
            GetRange = Data
        Else
            GetRange = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
End Function


It is simpler to delete the the next row then the previous row.  Allow .Offset(-1).Delete would work for this use case, it still should be avoided.
My code is using Union to delete the empty cell and the cells from the row above that need deleting in a single operation. This not only simplifies the code but is faster.

Sub RowAboveDelete()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = Target.Rows.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If Len(Target(r + 1, 1)) = 0 Then
            Union(Target(r + 1, 1), Target.Rows(r).Offset(, 1)).Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

If there is no formatting, using arrays will be exponentially faster then deleting cells.  But that is the subject for another post.

Thank you, I really appreciate your help, I've  just learned great, new things!

My pleasure @FotoDJ!

Loop through all cells in column A and populate the rows above.
Loading data from a sheet into an array for processing is more efficient when working with large datasets.
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim rngData As Range, lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rngDel As Range, arrData
    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), _
            Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row
        Set rngData = .Range("A1:D" & lastRow)
    End With
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i, 1)) = 0 And i > 1 Then
            For j = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
                arrData(i - 1, j) = arrData(i, j)
            Next
        End If
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDel = rngData.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
        rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub


If you'd like to retain the formatting (e.g., fill color, font) of rows with a blank cell in the first column, please try the following:
Sub Demo2()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rngDel As Range, arrData
    Dim lastRow As Long, ColCnt As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), _
            Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row
        ColCnt = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Set rngData = .Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, ColCnt)
    End With
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i, 1)) = 0 And i > 1 Then
            Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, ColCnt - 1).Copy Cells(i - 1, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDel = rngData.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
        rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub


Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

I wanted to keep the majority of your code and make it as simple as possible.
Option Explicit

Sub RowAboveDelete()

 'I made it here the ActiveSheet simply because I don't know which sheet you would like to use.
 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
 Dim lr As Long
 lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

 Dim i As Long
 
 For i = lr To 1 Step -1
   If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Then
    'Copy the Range into the above row
    'We are just copying the values here and not the formatting hence the " = " otherwise you could use ".Copy"
    ws.Range("B" & i - 1, "D" & i - 1).Value = ws.Range("B" & i, "D" & i).Value
    'Delete the Row that has been copied
    ws.Rows(i).Delete
   End If
Next i

'check the last cell again
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'make the bottom border thick again
With ws.Range("A" & lr, "D" & lr).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .Weight = xlThick
End With

End Sub


Copy the Range into the above row ?? Your code is copying FROM the row above into the row you are deleting. Line should be ws.Range("B" & i - 1, "D" & i - 1).Value = ws.Range("B" & i, "D" & i).Value

You are almost there, just need to copy the cell from above.
Sub RowAboveDelete()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the worksheet you are working on
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    ' Find the last row in column B
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Optimize performance - optional
    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    On Error Resume Next ' Prevent unexpected errors from halting the macro
    For i = lr To 2 Step -1 ' Loop from the last row upwards to row 2
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Then ' Check if cell in column A is empty
            If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i - 1, 1)) Then ' Ensure the row above is valid
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value ' Copy value from the row above
            End If
            ws.Rows(i - 1).Delete ' Delete the row above
        End If
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
    
    ' Restore application settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    MsgBox "Process completed successfully!", vbInformation
End Sub


Thank you, I really appreciate your help!
